# Please help me to choose books

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I have 4 books about math.

Can you help me to write a sequence of reading these books?

1.Algebra and Geometry(Alan F.Beardon) https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/0521890497/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1

2.Calculus (Frank Ayres, Jr.,Phd Elliott Mendelson)

3.Linear Algebra
https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/0071794565/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

4.Geometry https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/1107647835/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

I am still at school, but I went through all the material.
And tell me please, What math topics are covered at the University?

Comment: I suggest reading books about linear algebra and calculus these are the basis of math in the university. About the book of Geometry you will not need it in university

Answer (score 0):

What courses comprise a university math education varies from school to school and country to country. I worked for years at a small liberal arts college in the US. Our undergraduate program was essentially the calculus sequence, linear algebra, differential equations, abstract algebra, and introductory analysis, together with a course in foundations. We were occasionally able to offer special topics courses in topology and complex analysis.

This structure was fundamentally different from what was offered at my undergraduate and graduate institutions, which were major public research universities. We had courses in advanced linear algebra and a second course in differential equations. Qualified students were able to take graduate courses if they desired. The undergraduate sequences in algebra and analysis were both two semesters, and both were required for majors (as was complex analysis). At the school where I worked, we were only able to offer one semester of each due to staffing limitations and number of math majors.

The level at which courses are offered can vary a great deal as well. At stronger schools (with stronger students) analysis would be offered at the level of, say,  Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis. At my school, with not necessarily weaker, but certainly less prepared students, use of that text would have been folly.

To get to your actual question, books 1,2 and 3 seem reasonable to master. The book on geometry, maybe not so much. Many schools in the US offer courses in geometry for undergraduates and these are mostly a theoretical look at "elementary" geometry. We did not require the course for our major.